# Getting the URL of a file my app is opening via openURL:

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I configured my app with a custom file type. I added the information required in the Info.plist file (Document Types and Exported UTIs). Now iOS recognizes my file type and associates it with the app. So, for example, when I open Mail, and I see my file as an attachment, I can click on it and select to open with my app.

How I can get the URL of the file from my app? I tried to use `OpenUrl` on `UIApplication`, but it does not work.

Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution, but please put it in an answer below rather than into the body of your question. [It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120215/ended-up-solving-my-own-problem-question-what-to-do-with-the-post?lq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION FOUND

I state that I need a solution for Xamarin/C#, but I asked for a standard objective-c code to later translate in C#, becouse I could not find anything about that.

At the end this is the solution that worked for me:

In the *AppDelegate.cs* file I add this method:

```
public override bool OpenUrl (UIApplication application, NSUrl url, string sourceApplication, NSObject annotation)
{
     NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotification (NSNotification.FromName ("OpenMyFile", url));
     return true;
}
```

Then in my main controller, I add this in the "ViewDidLoad" method:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver ("OpenMyFile", openFileVoid);
```

And in the same class I add a new method:

```
public async void openFileVoid (NSNotification notification)
{
    NSUrl _filePath = (NSUrl)notification.Object;
    // Do what you need with this file path
}
```

I hope can be useful to someone! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it has nothing to do with `-[UIApplication openURL:]`.

As it was stated in [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/filemanagement/conceptual/documentinteraction_topicsforios/Articles/OpeningSupportedFileTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010412-SW1) :

> You receive information about the file to be
>   opened in the `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or
>   `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method of your application
>   delegate. If your application handles custom file types, you must
>   implement this delegate method (instead of the
>   `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method) and use it to initialize your
>   application.
>
> The options dictionary passed to the
>   `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or
>   `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method contains information
>   about the file to be opened.

You can read about it more in the doc.