# How to get the parameters and pass to the Model

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, appdelegate, openurl

Good afternoon. I`m using mvvmCross 5.2.0 and Xamarin.

I am trying to pass three parameters through a link and when opening my App, treat them in a Model, however I am not able to find how, by AppDelegate, I call a Model passing the parameters.

Link:

valdemar://?token=1234&name=Rafael

AppDelegate:

```
public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication application, NSUrl url, string sourceApplication, NSObject annotation)
        {
            ...
            //How to get the parameters and pass to the Model?

        }
```

Comment: It is simple to get the parameters , but what' the meaning by `passing to the model`? You mean create a global variable(Model class) in Appdelegate?

Comment: @ColeXia I need to use these two parameters in a Model. When I get them from the link in the AppDelegate, I need to pass those parameters there to the Model and there manage to work with them. For example: In the AppDelegate, I would receive a user and password through the link, and would pass to my LoginModel to log in.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660904/open-viewmodel-from-appdelegate maybe helpful

Comment: @ColeXia Hi my friend, I used the information from this link, see what you think, please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970246/getting-the-url-of-a-file-my-app-is-opening-via-openurl

Comment: `Notification`  is helpful ,have you solved your problem?

Comment: Yes my friend @ColeXia.